# Assuming Q* Qualia from OpenAi has achieved AGI and it's able to break AES encryption. How does this affect Monero?

Tags: security, encryption

Rumors have that OpenAI has achieved AGI. Assuming its true, and having that Q* Qualia is confirmed real as of today. The leaked documents a few weeks ago states they were able to break AES encryption. How would this new development affect Monero or any cryptocurrency for that matter?